# If you can not "Plot" a Function - how can you know if it is Convex or Non-Convex?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, convex-analysis

I understand that for functions defined over a continuous domain, there are some standard "tests" which can be used to determine if a function is Convex or Non-Convex (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition). Thus - even for very complicated functions with more than 3 variables (i.e. you can not plot a graph for more than 3 variables), we should be able to determine if any function defined over the continuous range is Convex or Non-Convex. (Note: I have heard that in many applied fields, Convex Functions are easier to optimize compared to Non-Convex Functions - this is why we are often interested in knowing whether a function is Convex or Non-Convex).

Recently, I posted a question (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7691/if-you-can-not-take-the-derivative-of-your-objective-function-is-convexity-i) about determining whether the Objective Function in the Travelling Salesperson Problem can be (fundamentally) considered as Convex or Non-Convex. I received some useful comments and answers here, but I still can not understand this.

For instance, in a very naïve sense - if I wanted to find out whether or not the function "y = sin(x)" is Convex or Non-Convex. I could plot this function and see if it passes the "visual test of convexity" ; if this function had multiple variables, I could use the more formal convexity conditions to algebraically determine whether this function was Convex or Non-Convex.

However, in the case of the [Travelling Salesperson Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), the Objective Function is not defined over a continuous domain. The inputs of the Objective Function in the Travelling Salesman Problem are "discrete", seeing as this problem is often considered as a "discrete combinatorial optimization problem". If I were to look at the Objective Function of the Travelling Salesperson Problem and the conditions under which this Objective Function is being optimized:

[image]

How we apply the Convexity Test Definition to the following function:  **Sum_i=1:n(Sum_j=1:n(c_ij*x_ij))** ? This function can not be plotted at all - thus, how do we know if this function is Convex or Non-Convex?

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned Wikipedia's convexity article. There you can find : For $w_1 , … , w_n \geq 0 $ and if $f_1 , … , f_n$ are all convex, then so is $w_1 f_1 + ⋯ + w_n f_n $. Apply this with $w_i:=c_i$ and $f_i:=x_i$

Comment: Thank you Maksim! I consulted the Wikipedia article and unfortunately, I still don't understand this point. I understand that if f1...fn are convex, if you then multiply f1...fn by some constants w1...wn, then the result product (w1f1 + ... + wnfn) will also be convex. But in the case of discrete combinatorics functions -  how can f1...fn be considered as convex in the first place? Can you please help me understand this? Thank you!

Comment: Even if the $c_i$ are not $\ge 0$, a linear function is always convex.

Comment: Do you know the definition of convex function?  Do you know the definition of linear function?

Comment: The doubly indexed sum involves $\,c_{ij}\,$ and $\,x_{ij}.\,$ The problem is that the distances $\,c_{ij}\,$ are presumably real numbers while the $\,x_{ij}\,$ are binary $\,0,1\,$ valued but these are also real numbers. You have to decide if the sum is a function of the $\,c_{ij}\,$ or else the $\,x_{ij}\,$ in order to determine if it is convex. However, in both cases, it is a linear function and hence automatically convex.

Comment: Please learn how to link.  Nobody wants to read URLs in a mathematical question.